# Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes

Tags: automata

I need to find the Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes for the language $$ L = \Sigma^*\setminus \left( \{\epsilon, cc \} \cup \{ cca^i: i\geq 2 \} \right) $$ over $\Sigma = \{a, b, c \}$

I'm familiar with the idea of separating suffix, but I really don't know where to start here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, note the the Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes for a language $L$ is the same as the Myhill-Nerode classes for its complement $\overline{L}$. This follows immediately by definition, and I leave it you (it also appears [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33954/how-to-prove-that-the-myhill-nerode-equivalence-classes-for-l-are-the-same-as-fo)).

So given $\Sigma = \{a, b, c\}$, we need to find the Myhill-Nerode classes for $\overline{L} = \{ \epsilon, cc\}\cup \{cca^i: i\geq 2 \}$. There are many ways to do so, one can, for example, consider what happens in a minimal deterministic automaton for the language - it is known that the states of the minimal deterministic automaton correspond to the Myhill-Nerode classes. Yet, the given language is simple enough, you can actually experiment with it a bit and show that the following are the equivalence class for $\overline{L}$ (indeed, $\overline{L}$ has a simple structure - every word of length at least $4$ in the laguage is of the form $cca^i$, so clearly all these words are equivalent. Then, you can look at words of length < 4, and try to see which among them are equivalent, etc.):

- $C_1 = \{ \epsilon\}$.
- $C_2 =  \{ c\}$.
- $C_3 =  \{ cc\}$.
- $C_4 = \{ cca\}$.
- $C_5 = \{ cca^i: i\geq 2\}$.
- $C_6 = \Sigma^*\setminus \left( \bigcup_{i\in [5]} C_i\right)$.

Clearly the 5 sets above partition $\Sigma^*$, so to show that they are indeed the Myhill-Nerode classes, we need to show that all the words in the same set are Myhill-Nerode equivalent, and for every $ 1\leq i < j \leq 6$, it holds that the words in the set $C_i$ are not equivalent to the words in the set $C_j$.

There you go, try to prove that the above sets are indeed the equivalence classes. That should be easy enough now.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence classes for $L$ are the same as those for $\overline{L} = \{cca^i \, : \, i \ge 2\} \cup \{\varepsilon, cc\}$.

All the words in $\{cca^i \, : \, i \ge 2\}$ belong to the same equivalence class $C_1$.
Indeed let $\alpha, \beta \in \{cca^i \, : \, i \ge 2\}$ and consider any extension  $x$, if $x \neq a^k$ for some $k$, then neither $\alpha x$ nor $\beta x$ belong to $\overline{L}$. Otherwise they both belong to $\overline{L}$.

The word $cc$ belongs to some equivalence class $C_2 \neq C_1$. Indeed $a$ is a distinguishing extension for $cc$ and $ccaa \in C_1$.

The word $\varepsilon$ belongs to some equivalence class $C_3 \not\in \{C_1, C_2\}$. Indeed (i) $cc$ is a distinguishing extension for $\varepsilon$ and $cc \in C_2$, and (ii) $a$ is a distinguishing extension for $\varepsilon$ and $ccaa \in C_1$.

The word $c$ belongs to some equivalence class $C_4 \not\in \{C_1, C_2, C_3\}$. Indeed $\varepsilon$ is a distinguishing extension for $c$ and any word in $C_1$, $C_2$, or $C_3$.

The word $cca$  belongs to some equivalence class $C_5 \not\in \{C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4\}$.
Indeed (i) $\varepsilon$ is a distinguishing extension for $cca$ and any word in $C_1$, $C_2$, or $C_3$, and (ii) $a$ is a distinguishing extension for $cca$ and $c \in C_4$.

All other words $\gamma$ do not start with any prefix of $cca^*$. Therefore there exist no extension $x$ such that $\gamma x \in \overline{L}$.
Moreover (i) $\varepsilon$ is a distinguishing extension for $\gamma$ and any word in $C_1$, $C_2$, or $C_3$, and there exists at least one distinguishing extension for $c \in C_4$ (namely $c$), and for $cca \in C_5$ (namely $a$).
This shows that all these words $\gamma$ belong to the same equivalence class.

The equivalence classes are then:
$$
\{cca^i \, : \, i \ge 2\}, \; \{cc\}, \; \{ \varepsilon\}, \; \{ c\}, \; \{ cca \}, \Sigma^* \setminus \{cca^k \, : \, k \ge 0 \}.
$$