# Prove or disprove that a any language L and its complement have the same amount of equivalence classes

Tags: formal-languages

The question is:

> Given a language $L$ (not necessarily regular), prove or disprove that $Eq(L) = Eq(\overline{L})$.
>
> Where $Eq(L)$ is the amount of equivalence classes the language L has, and $\overline{L}$ is the complement of $L$.

My intuition says the statement is true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Equivalence classes… related to which equivalence relation?

Comment: Hint: If $S$ is an equivalence class of the Myhill–Nerode relation of $L$, then it is also an equivalence class of the Myhill–Nerode relation of $\overline{L}$.

Comment: See for instance [How to prove that the Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes for L are the same as for its complement?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33954/4287).

Comment: @Nathaniel I didn't think I had to specify, sorry. The equivalence classes of L under the equivalence relation ~L, and the equivalence classes of L' under the equivalence relation ~L'.